# Naming XSDs in wsdl generated by WCF

Tags: wcf, xsd, wsdl, bpel

We are working on a `WCF` service which is being consumed by `BPEL`. When `BPEL` imports the `WSDL`, it reads the `XSDs` as below:

_

```
http://Server_Name/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd0

_http://Server_Name/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd1

_http://Server_Name/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd2
```

so on and so forth.

This random naming of `XSDs` is creating a lot of churn, as whenever there is a contract change, `BPEL` again reloads the entire `WSDL` and a random number suffix will be added to each `XSD`. `BPEL` team will have to then again open each `XSD` to find out the change.

Is there a way by which `WCF` can stop generating these random `XSDs` and give each `XSD` a proper name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome this problem, We installed .NET 4.5 to generate single wsdl which properly names the XSDs and has no XSD import statements.

Answer (score 0):

What about downloading and properly naming these XSDs during design time instead of linking to these resources? The benefit would be that schema changes are under your control. I think this is preferable as long as it remains unclear if and if so under what circumstances the BPEL engine may reload the XSDs from these resources. If the schema changes, it should me made known explicitly and a new version of the process model should be deployed.

Comment: BPEL devs are downloading the XSDs and naming each one, but when there is a contract change, they have to again re-download the XSDs from WSDL, rename it and go through the churn of identifying which element has been modified.

Is it possible for WCF to display a hand coded WSDL (which has proper XSD schemalocations and XSD names)? If so, i am happy to take the pain and hand code my WSDL with proper schemalocations and names.